# Create React SyntheticEvent?

Tags: reactjs

How can I create my own React [SyntheticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#syntheticevent)?

I'm creating a custom event, and I want the API to match React's exactly.

Answer (score 0):

React defines synthetic events according to the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/).

With that said, I don't think there's an easy way to extend `SyntheticEvent`, but you could create a simple fake event like so:

```
export default class MyFakeEvent {
  constructor(target) {
    this.description = 'My fake event';
    this._noop = () => {};
    this.preventDefault = this._noop;
  }
}
```

This is just an example though. You could add/remove to this as needed based on what you're trying to accomplish.